# UITableView setEditing doesn't animate label constraint change

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

So, I have a custom tableview cell in tableview and when I set the editing mode on with the `[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];` code.

It sets the editing mode but the problem is that my label on the cell just teleports to it's new location as it is pushed left when the reorder control shows itself. How can I animate the constraint change when the editing happens?

Picture of the my tableview cell:(The right constraint clearly increases when the editing goes on but it's not animated and I want it to be)

[image: Pic1]

Edit: Here is my cell's setEditing.
I have tried to do it in many ways but the animation just doesn't work for some reason, the change happens instantly.

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             self.labelConstraint.constant = 100;
                             [self layoutIfNeeded];

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {


         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your cell's implementation of `setEditing:animated:`?

Comment: Try add `[self setNeedsLayout];` before `[self layoutIfNeeded];`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I've having the same problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem 5 years later. Seriously, this hasn't been fixed yet?? I just filed for code-level support so we'll see what Apple says about it.

Comment: I'm still stuck with this 6 years later... Has anybody figured it out? @Trev14  ?

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me if I change constraint before animation block

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    self.containerLeftConstraint.constant = editing ? EditingIndent : 0.0f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{

                         [self layoutIfNeeded];
                     }];

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. In my case I have a right justified label in the cell and the lack of animation is painfully apparent even with a plethora of `layoutIfNeeded()` calls at every imaginable point in `setEditing(:animated:)`. If the label is left justified and only constrained to the left edge of the cell contentView everything looks fine, like the contentView is smoothly animated to the right so the delete button can show on the left. Layout animations inside of the contentView happen instantly though :/